# Need help on very strange iPhone currency addition and subtraction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, nsdecimalnumber

This is 'sorta' urgent since my app just went live today.

My app works fine in the emulator, fine when I copy it to my phone, iPad and other iPhones.  We tested the heck out of the app.  I submitted it to the appstore and it is now approved and live but an error occurs only with the downloaded appstore app.

Basically i am rebalancing a bill using NSDecimal and number formatters.  In the emulator and phone when I step through the code all is well.  But the appstore bundle wigs out.  It almost appears that the data that I am adding and subtracting is not being initalized.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

I know this post is completely vague but trying to figure out where to start debugging if the code in emulator works fine.

--UPDATE-- adding code

```
 -(void)balanceBill:(UITextField*)textField 
 {
//save the text field data
int row                         = [textField tag] - 900;
NSString *enteredSplitAmount    = [formatter stringWithNoCurrency:[textField text]];
[theGuestTotals replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:enteredSplitAmount];

//Get data object
BillDataObject* data    = [self theAppDataObject];

int changedSplitBy  = 0;
UITableViewCell *cell;
UITextField     *cellTextField;

double          adjustedBill = 0.0;
NSString        *guestAmountFromArray;
//NSString        *guestAmountAdjusted;

//Figure out how many guests did NOT have their bill changed & get new bill total
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [theGuestTotals count]; i++)
{
    guestAmountFromArray        = [theGuestTotals objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([guestAmountFromArray   isEqualToString:data.splitByAmountChanged]) 
    {
        changedSplitBy++;
    }    
    //Adding ALL guest amounts to get a NEW Bill Total
    adjustedBill += [guestAmountFromArray doubleValue];
}

if (changedSplitBy == 0)
    changedSplitBy = 1;


//Convert newBill to decimal
NSDecimalNumber *adjustedBillTotal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:adjustedBill];
NSDecimalNumber *originalBillTotal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:data.totalBill];    

NSDecimalNumber *splitBy = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:changedSplitBy];
NSDecimalNumber *updatedGuestAmount;

//Figure out the the difference is between the new amount and the old amount
NSDecimalNumber *adjustedBillTotalDifference = [originalBillTotal decimalNumberBySubtracting:adjustedBillTotal];

//figure out the difference each guest who did not have their bill changed difference
NSDecimalNumber *guestSplitAmountDifference = [adjustedBillTotalDifference decimalNumberByDividingBy:splitBy];

//loop through array of guest totals to see if a guest total if different from the original split amout
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [theGuestTotals count]; i++)
{
    guestAmountFromArray = [theGuestTotals objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([guestAmountFromArray isEqualToString:data.splitByAmountChanged]) 
    {
        NSDecimalNumber *guestAmount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[theGuestTotals objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath  = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        cell                    = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cellTextField           = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:i+900];

        //add the split amount to the guest amount
        updatedGuestAmount = [guestAmount decimalNumberByAdding:guestSplitAmountDifference];
        //update the textfield with UPDATED amount
        cellTextField.text      = [formatter stringWithNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle numberToFormat:updatedGuestAmount];            
        //replace the guest amount in the array with the UPDATED amount
        [theGuestTotals         replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[formatter stringWithNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle numberToFormat:updatedGuestAmount]];
    } else {
        //Not equal so just update the amount from what it was...
        //this might not be needed but I need to format if it is...
        cellTextField.text      = [formatter stringWithNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle numberToFormat:            [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:guestAmountFromArray]];
    }
}

//Now all guests who were not edited GOT updated now save that update for the next time this function is run
data.splitByAmountChanged = [formatter stringWithNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle numberToFormat:updatedGuestAmount];

//Clear out adjustedBill to get NEW totals after we updated each guest in the loop above
adjustedBill = 0;
//Lets see if we are over or under and do the 'REDISTRIBUTE'
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [theGuestTotals count]; i++)
{
    adjustedBill += [[theGuestTotals objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
}

adjustedBillTotal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:adjustedBill];

if ([originalBillTotal compare:adjustedBillTotal] == NSOrderedAscending) 
{  
    [warningImage setHidden:NO];
    NSDecimalNumber *overage = [adjustedBillTotal decimalNumberBySubtracting:originalBillTotal];

    [overUnderLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ over",[formatter stringWithNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle numberToFormat:overage]]];

   // [self disableDone];
    [self enableRedistribute];
} 
else if ([originalBillTotal compare:adjustedBillTotal] == NSOrderedDescending) 
{
    [warningImage setHidden:NO];        
    NSDecimalNumber *underage = [originalBillTotal decimalNumberBySubtracting:adjustedBillTotal]; 

    [overUnderLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ under",[formatter stringWithNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle numberToFormat:underage]]];

   // [self disableDone];
    [self enableRedistribute];
} 
else 
{
    [warningImage setHidden:YES];        
    overUnderLabel.text = @"";
    //[self enableDone];
    [self disableRedistribute];
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have an example of the math problems? Can you get device logs from a device where the error is happening? Does the deployment device OS match the development device OS? Does the locale (region) match?

Comment: i do.  i can paste them in.  i just noticed i had 2 dead store errors on some variables i am using.  i cleaned that up and no errors on the emulator or phone.

Comment: did not mean to hit enter...there are no 'errors' but miscalculations.  it looks like it is subtracting from a very large number.  basically if the bill is 60.00 i split it 4 ways each guest has a 15.00 bill.  i allow the user to change the 15.00 to whatever they want.  so the first guest can be 20.00.  on the completion of entering the new data i then tally up ALL of the fields and get a total of 65.00 I then subtract that from the orginal (60) to get 5.00.  that 5 then is divided by who is left (3) and I then add that to the total that each guest has (15).  what is happening the...

Comment: the number that comes back is (172,845,645.98).  no clue where that is coming from.

Comment: This sounds a lot like type/formatting errors to me. Are you using ints somewhere? Or, how to you print out this number? %d? %f? %@? Particularly this 5/3 seems prone to errors

Comment: no ints.  only nsdecimalnumbers.  i am using a numberformatter to print out the decimal.  any reason why it would only show up on the app from the appstore?  the phones i used to test with work but when i downloaded it from the store it acts up.  i am not setting locale anywhere and in the appstore i chose US for the store (fyi first app)

Comment: I honestly don't think there's anything special about an app coming from the App Store. It's much more likely that you have a programming error that was undiscovered until now.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to help you, other than to suggest that you add your calculation code to the question above. Then anyone who reads this question can look for any issues.

Comment: you guys are right.  it most likely is a coding issue but if i use the same values from the app from the store on my emulator and dev phone everything is fine and no errors in the log.

Comment: Also, make sure to `NSLog` every step of the calculation and tell us where the number goes crazy

Comment: @jiayow the thing is the numbers do not go crazy on the emulator or dev phone.

Comment: You're using Debug on emulator and dev phone right? Change the setting s to the settings you use in release (eg optimizations etc). Install the app store version on the dev phone and compare

Comment: @JiaYow nice tip.  i changed the scheme to release mode and all is still good :)  i think i might just resubmit the app.

Comment: What do you mean with "still good"? You said it calculated a bill of like 172 million. How's that good?

Comment: @JiaYow - first off I would like to say thanks for helping me.  still good means the app in release mode on my dev phone is not showing miscalculation.  release mode and debug mode on dev phone and dev ipod  calculates correctly.  the app from the appstore on dev phone and dev ipod caclulate incorrectly.  i think i need to sleep on it and look at this in the morning.  i appreciate everyones help, just a weird issue

Comment: From a quick look, I don't see why you would be getting such an incorrect number.  But the code you are using is far more complicated than needed.  Also, you lose the opportunity to debug problems when you cascade results from one method into another.  If an inner operation fails, you won't be able to see the incorrect result before it gets used by the next method.

Comment: i am going to try and rewrite the method over.  for the life of me i cannot replicate the problem that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a dead store issue with 2 variables in my method.  Even though I set them later on I removed them and re-submitted the app.  The issue went away.

Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your attempt to use the UITableViewCells for data storage.  You don't push data into the cells,  you wait for the UITableView to call YOUR cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

The UITableView will only retain enough cells to fill the screen.  As soon as one scrolls out of sight, it will be released.  When your loop tries to retrieve it again with cellForRowAtIndexPath: it will allocate a new cell to give you.  While your loop may initialize it, it won't be stored or used by the UITable object.